# Has anyone worked on a built-in CLI terminal [w/ drush]?

Tags: drush, modal-dialogs, dashboard

What would make my experience with clients/end-users easier is if there was a self-contained GUI-like terminal that would be exclusive to their drupal 7 subsite in a multi-site configuration. This would allow them to be full-stack developers without the headache of managing *nix users?

The only reference I could find was for Drupal 6 - https://drupal.org/project/terminal.

In the meantime, the way I can think of manually achieving some of this is to write custom forms on a user dash (page--front.tpl.php) that would trigger drush calls on the server side for particular (custom) tasks. Maybe add some ajaxy for wiz-bang.

Now granted, a lot of the customs tasks I can think of atm can be achieved via drupal modules - such as editing css, limiting access to module uploads, and even exposing features. It's just turning each one of those on/off for over 100+ sites is cumbersome, and so it'd be nice to leave it up to the end-user to manage their own site.

Without paying Pantheon to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming Drush 7 now has `drush core-cli` which used the [Boris shell](https://github.com/d11wtq/boris/)